# Git didn't recognize rename of a file

Tags: git

I renamed one Java source file from *Multiplechoice.java* to *MultipleChoice.java*.

Unfortunately Git didn't recognize this change. So when someone clones or pulls my repository he or she will have to do the renaming manually, because otherwise the project can't build because this class is used in other classes.

How do I make Git recognize this change in order to commit and push it to the repository?

Comment: @torazaburo Does that matter? Case insensitive file systems are available for all the current major OSes, and the way to solve the problem is the same for all of them, isn't it?

Comment: FYI: It is Windows 7.

Comment: You could rename it to something else, then back to the intended name

Comment: @MattMcNabb this did not work. I tried that before posting the question. But the accepted answers works for me.

Comment: @SimonTenbeitel using `git mv`, I meant, if it didn't work to `git mv` it directly.

Comment: In Windows NTFS file names are case insensitive (but case preserving). That's probably why git didn't get it. `git mv` however should work :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Git **move** function:

```
git mv "Multiplechoice.java" "MultipleChoice.java"
```